# Is there a @class tag in Aspectj like @annotation tag?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj

There is a @annotation tag in Spring AOP Aspectj and we can easily annotation object. E.g:

Custom Annotation:

```java
public @interface Authorize
```

```java
@Before("@annotation(authorize)")
public void adviseAnnotatedMethods(JoinPoint joinPoint, Authorize authorize) {
   System.out.println(authorize);
}
```

I wonder whether there is a @class tag like @annotation?

```java
@Before("@class(customClass)")
public void adviseAnnotatedMethods(JoinPoint joinPoint, CustomClass customClass {
   System.out.println(customClass);
}
```

Actually, in here, my aim is to reach CustomClass object. I know that I can reach it from jointPoint.getArgs() as checking (object instanceOf CustomClass). But I wonder there is a easy way to do it?

---

**Update: full code**

Exact Code:

I have a controller method:

```java
@GetMapping("user/waiting/{accountId}/{userId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getWaitingItems(@Custom CustomUser user) {
    ...
}
```

I have an annotation like below:

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Custom {}
```

CustomUser:

```java
public class CustomUser {
    private Long accountId;
    private Long userId;
    private User user;
}
```

Aspectj methods:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* *(.., @Custom (*), ..))")
void annotatedCustom() {}

@Before("annotatedCustom()")
public void adviseMethodsOfAnnotatedClass(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    CustomUser cu = getArg(joinPoint);
    ...handle it.
}

private CustomClass getArg(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    for (Object a : joinPoint.getArgs()) {
        if (a instanceof CustomClass) {
            return (CustomClass) a;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Before, after or even around an object does not make any sense at all, so please elaborate on your question a bit more. we use aspect to do some business before, after or around a specific method, but What do you mean by making aspect for an object?

Comment: Have you tried `((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod()` ?
then you can get the CustomUser that annotated with @Custom

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad, First of all, this code is working like above. Secondly, in here, I want to escape from getArgs or MethodSignature. I think that there should be easier way to reach it.

Comment: Aha, you mean, you want an easier way than MethodSignature or getArgs

Comment: Yes, E.g:Authorize authorize; this annotation can be reached like @annotation(authorize) easily. So if it's a class, how can I reach it like that easily?

Comment: Your pointcut looks for method arguments of any type annotated by `@Custom` in any given position in the signature, as if you could never rely on the type and the parameter position. (1) So do you want to handle other types too or just `CustomClass`? (2) Can you rely on a relative parameter position (e.g. 1st, 2nd, 3rd from left or right)? Your answers to my questions determine my answer. And besides, your `...` hides information about how specific or generic your aspect should be. I hate guessing, then being wrong and having to iterate 7x in order to answer a question.

Comment: Besides, your helper method `getArg` returns `CustomClass`, but in your advice you assign the result to a `CustomUser` variable. This looks inconsistent. What you call "full code" in your own description looks more like pseudo code or a result of copy & paste with deleted portions (2x `...`) and maybe changed class names without any consistency check after you modified the code. This makes it hard to reason about your code. A real [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be better. Ambiguous code leads to ambiguous answers - or plain wrong ones.

Comment: @kriegaex 1. it can be only @ Custom CustomUser. 2. Other paremeters are not important.

Comment: You misunderstood question 2. I didn't ask about importance of other parameters but about relative parameter position of the parameter you are interested in. Please spend some more effort in your explanations if you need help. Thank you.